# Can we create and send oAuth request to an api from asp .net framework 2.0 and 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, https, oauth-2.0

System.Net.Http is available in .net version 4.5 and above. I have the below code in .Net core. Need an equivalent code to connect to a api with oauth authentication.

Below is the code i used to connect from .NET core project.

public async Task GetOAuthTokenAsync(string tokenUri, string scope)

{

JWTToken jwtToken = null;

try

{

string clientid = "";

string clientsceretCode = "";

HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

string plainCredential = $"{clientid}:{clientsceretCode}";

var plaintextbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainCredential);

var encodedCredential = Convert.ToBase64String(plaintextbytes);

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>

{ return true; };

using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))

{

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenUri);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedCredential);

var inputParams = new Dictionary<string, string>

{

{"grant_type", "client_credentials"},

{"scope", scope}

};

string msg = string.Empty;

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(inputParams);

content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//HttpContent requestParams = new FormUrlEncodedContent(inputParams);

tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

msg = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// Verification

if (tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)

{

var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

jwtToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

}

}

}

catch(Exception ex)

{

Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}

return jwtToken;

}

Comment: Use [System.Net.WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-2.0)

Comment: 1. You need to add swagger support.
2. Add swagger support for OAuth, you can enter the token on the swagger page:
Modify the following code in the SwaggerConfig.cs file:
.EnableSwaggerUi(char =>){
    //Enable Oauth support
    c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
    //c.DocumentTitle("My Swagger UI");
}